# rbenv での Ruby 2.2.1 のインストールに失敗する

Tags: ruby, rbenv

rbenv で Ruby 2.2.1 のインストールを試みましたが失敗しました。
Ubuntu 14.04 と ruby-build 20150303 を使っています。

```
$ rbenv install 2.2.1
Downloading ruby-2.2.1.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/5a4de38068eca8919cb087d338c0c2e3d72c9382c804fb27ab746e6c7819ab28
Installing ruby-2.2.1...

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 14.04 using ruby-build 20150303)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20150304173607.22408
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20150304173607.22408.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling ossl_digest.c
compiling ossl_x509req.c
compiling ossl_asn1.c
installing default openssl libraries
linking shared-object psych.so
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20150304173607.22408/ruby-2.2.1/ext/psych'
linking shared-object openssl.so
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20150304173607.22408/ruby-2.2.1/ext/openssl'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20150304173607.22408/ruby-2.2.1'
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20150304173607.22408.log
```

とあるのでまず `/tmp/ruby-build.20150304173607.22408.log` を見てみると、以下のようなログが残っていました。

```
linking shared-object fiddle.so
/usr/bin/ld: ./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a(raw_api.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
./libffi-3.2.1/.libs/libffi.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-linux/fiddle.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20150304174118.5523/ruby-2.2.1/ext/fiddle'
make[1]: *** [ext/fiddle/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

ruby-build の wiki にもありますが、`libffi-dev` パッケージをインストールすることで解決します。

```
$ sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/wiki#build-failure-of-fiddle-with-ruby-220