# VagrantとCentOS7環境下でRuby及びRailsをインストールしたい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, vagrant

VagrantとCentOS7環境下にてRuby及びRailsをインストールしたいと思っています。
[前回](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/65954/rbenv-install-2-7-1%E3%81%A7%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC-mkdir-cannot-create-directory-usr-local-rbenv-versio)、失敗したため詳しい手順をご存知の方がいましたら順序立ててご教示いただけますと幸いです。

追記

下記のコマンドまで進みましたが
エラーが出ました。原因がわかりません。。。

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ rbenv install 2.7.1
Downloading ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.7.1...

BUILD FAILED (CentOS Linux 7 using ruby-build 20200401-9-g3ef704e)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20200427052059.2195.A64Isy
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20200427052059.2195.log

Last 10 log lines:
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:846:in `block (2 levels) in install_default_gem'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:279:in `open_for_install'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:845:in `block in install_default_gem'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:835:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:835:in `install_default_gem'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:799:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:950:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:947:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:947:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-all] Error 1
```

Comment: [こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/65972/2808)に書かれている、アンインストール後に実行すべきことがそのまま回答になりそうですが、どういう点が問題だったでしょうか。問題/疑問点を具体的に書いた方が回答がつきやすくなるかと考えます。

Comment: 失礼しました。まず冒頭のコマンドをやってみたのですがそんなコマンドは見つからないと出てしまいます。[vagrant@localhost ~]$ git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
-bash: git: command not found

Comment: この件に関しては、お手持ちのOS（WindowsやMacOS）の基礎知識から仮想化技術（virtualboxやVagrant）、仮想化OS（CentOS、Linuxの処理系）の知識及びRubyおよびRailsの基礎知識からビルドまでさらにはWeb系のソフトウェアの知識が必要になり、なかなか広範囲な質問の印象で、回答が付きづらいと思います。大変面倒ですが、失敗したところを一個一個質問していったほうが良いかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。前回失敗というのは、CentOS７環境下でRuby、Railsのインストール をわからない中、我流で行ったため、エラーが出て最終的にやり直そうと思ってもアンインストールをできなくなりました。そこで初めからCentOS７を入れ直し、今度は間違いないようにインストールしたいと思っています。そこで前回教えていただいた方法でインストールしようと思っているのですが、上記コメントにあるように最初のコマンドでつまづいております。。

Comment: @ligtning この場合、まず解決すべきなのは「git コマンドが使えない」で、質問もそれに合わせた内容になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど、GITをインストールしなければいけないという理解でよろしいでしょうか？コマンドは、調べるとsudo yum install gitでできるようですが、前回インストールに所構わずSudoを使ったせいでごちゃごちゃになったということで、そちらは使わない方がいいのではと思い、yum install git　のコマンドを試したところ、下記のような結果になってしまいました。Sudoは使っていいところと良くないところがあるのでしょうか？すいません、使いどころがわかっておりません。。
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
You need to be root to perform this command.

Comment: @ligtning エラーメッセージを機械翻訳で構わないので自分で読む習慣を付けることをお勧めします。最後に「You need to be root to perform this command. / このコマンドを実行するには root である必要がある」と出ています。 / どんな時に `sudo` を使うかは [関連質問への回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/65956) に簡単な説明を既に載せていますので再度確認してみてください。

Comment: すいません、ありがとうございます。確認させていただきました。これでRubyのインストールができるかと思いきや、追記のコマンドまで完了したところでエラーが出てしまいました。翻訳もしましたが、
原因がわかりません。。。

Comment: メッセージに表示されている通り、実行時のログ `/tmp/ruby-build.20200427052059.2195.log` の内容を確認してください (行数がどれくらいあるか分かりませんが、必要に応じて質問に追記してください)。 / 画面には最後の10行しか表示されていないので、第三者には「何かエラーがあった」ことしか分かりません。 / 例えばエラーで検索すると [こちらの手順](https://qiita.com/vranometria/items/d4a97e72c5b4366d2f22) などがヒットします。

Comment: 重複候補: [rbenv での Ruby 2.2.1 のインストールに失敗する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/7432)

Comment: `rbenv install` 時のエラーは、前の質問の[私の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/65972/19110)で説明している `yum install` の部分で解決できます。ログファイルの末尾のあたりを読んでください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

公式のGetting Started, [4.1 Starting up the Web Server](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#starting-up-the-web-server)で `rails server`コマンドを実行し、 "Yay! You’re on Rails!"のページが表示されるところまで確認しました:

```sh
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum -y install gdbm-devel openssl-devel readline-devel zlib-devel

# SQLite >= 3.8 インストール(ここでは最新版の3.31.1をインストール)
# https://www.sqlite.org/download.html
curl -s https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3310100.tar.gz | tar xz -C /tmp
cd /tmp/sqlite-autoconf-3310100
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install

# nodejs v12(LTS) インストール
# https://nodejs.org/ja/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions-enterprise-linux-fedora-and-snap-packages より
# https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#rpminstall
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo bash -
sudo yum -y install nodejs

# yarn インストール
# https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#centos-stable
curl --silent --location https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo
sudo yum -y install yarn

# rbenv, rbenv-build インストール
# https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#basic-github-checkout
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
cd ~/.rbenv && src/configure && make -C src
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
mkdir -p "$(rbenv root)"/plugins
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build

# ruby インストール
rbenv install 2.7.1
rbenv global 2.7.1

# sqlite3 最新版利用設定
# https://url4u.jp/centos7-rails6-sqlite3/
bundle config build.sqlite3 "--with-sqlite3-lib=/usr/local/lib"

# rails インストール
# https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#installing-rails
gem install rails
```

[サンプル`Vagrantfile`](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so65998)

---

質問へのコメントでも示唆されていますが、質問文中にあるエラーはビルドに必要なライブラリが不足しているためで、何が不足しているかはエラーログに出力されています。

Comment: ありがとうございます！なんとか解決できました！